# Use of underclared identifier with _varname when @property (nonatomic) BOOL varname declared

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode8

Met very strange bug in `Xcode 8`:

I got property in `.h` file:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isInAirmode;
```

And accessors in `.m`:

```
- (void)setIsInAirmode:(BOOL)isInAirmode
{
    _isInAirmode = isInAirmode;
    [self da_postEvent:self.isInAirmode ? DAEventAirON : DAEventAirOFF];
}

- (BOOL)isInAirmode
{
    return _isInAirMode || _isTrailer;
}
```

And I got compilation error. But when I remove getter, everything is fine.  Why is that?

[image: xcode 8 bug]

Derived data was cleaned several times, I'm just wondering how is this possible?

Comment: If you override both the getter and setter then the property isn't auto-synthesized so no ivar will be made for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bag. Same behavior on Xcode 7.
When you implement getter, LLMV doesn't generate instance variable, because it doesn't know, do you actually need that.
So you need add it manually.
There are several ways how to do that:
In class definition or in class extension or in class implementation, or even with `@synthesize isInAirmode = _isInAirmode;`

And a common advices in code style for bool properties:
Declare them without `is` verb, add `is` in getter.
In yours cate it would be:

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, getter = isInAirmode) BOOL inAirmode;
```

.m

```
@synthesize inArimode = _inArimode;

- (void)setInAirmode:(BOOL)inAirmode
{
    if (_inArimode == inArimode) {
        return;
    }

    _inAirmode = inAirmode;
    [self inAirmodeDidChange];
}

- (BOOL)isInAirmode
{
    return _inAirMode || _trailer;
}

- (void)inAirmodeDidChange
{
    [self da_postEvent:self.isInAirmode ? DAEventAirON : DAEventAirOFF];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you would require to specific

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isInAirmode;
```

as

```
@property (assign,getter= _isInAirmode) BOOL isInAirmode;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that for BOOLs the ***is*** prefix is internally reserved for the getter of the variable. In https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html it says:

> Unless specified otherwise, a getter method should use the same name
>   as the property. For a property called firstName, the accessor method
>   should also be called firstName. The exception to this rule is for
>   Boolean properties, for which the getter method should start with is.
>   For a property called paused, for example, the getter method should be
>   called isPaused.
>
> The setter method for a property should use the form setPropertyName:.
>   For a property called firstName, the setter method should be called
>   setFirstName:; for a Boolean property called paused, the setter method
>   should be called setPaused:.
>
> Although the @property syntax allows you to specify different accessor
>   method names, you should only do so for situations like a Boolean
>   property

So, you shouldn't use the prefix ***is***.
Simply change the name of your BOOL to e.g.:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL inAirmode;
```

Then you can use ***_inAirmode*** in the setter.

Comment: thank for the answer, it did't help, same errors. 

@property (assign,getter= _isInAirmode) BOOL isInAirmode; - is fine

Comment: I tried with just changing the name and it worked. Are you sure the same errors appeared?